# How to add new column in quote_item table?

Tags: magento2

In magento 2 I want to add column in `quote_item` table.

How can i add that column,i am new in magento

Please help me

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add column like this

```
namespace [Name]\[Modulename]\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
 */
public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface    $context)
  {
    $installer = $setup;

    $installer->startSetup();

    $eavTable = $installer->getTable('quote_item');

    $columns = [
        'customname' => [
            'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'nullable' => false,
            'comment' => 'customname',
        ],

    ];

    $connection = $installer->getConnection();
    foreach ($columns as $name => $definition) {
        $connection->addColumn($eavTable, $name, $definition);
    }

    $installer->endSetup();
}
}
```

Using this code you can add column in `quote_item` table

Comment: I tried the same code but it didn't work for me. Could you please help?

Comment: @IpsitaRout can you create new question with your code?

Comment: This code worked for me after changing version in etc/module.xml.  Tx

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php


namespace Test\TestAgain\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetupFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetup;
use Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetup;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{


    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {


         $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        $connection = $installer->getConnection();
        $connection->addColumn($installer->getTable('quote'), 'custom_column', [
            'type'     => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'nullable' => true,
            'comment'  => 'Custom Column Name'
        ]);
        $connection->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales_order'), 'custom_column', [
            'type'     => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'nullable' => true,
            'comment'  => 'Custom Column Name'
        ]);

        $installer->endSetup();


        }
}
```

Note: If you face any issue, it may be due to the module that you have already installed. As you know, if the module is already installed then setup:upgrade command does not install schema. You will need to look into your setup_module table, delete your module from the table and re-run the php bin/magento setup:upgrade command.

Answer (score 1):

I have some complains with accepted answer. We should avoid operating over tables, especially core tables. The better way is to use `QuoteSetup`. The other issue that all answers implements is usage of `SchemaSetup` script when we should use `DataSetup`. That's because `quote_item` columns are considered as attributes in core Magento.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * Quote setup factory
     *
     * @var QuoteSetupFactory
     */
    private $quoteSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param QuoteSetupFactory $quoteSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        QuoteSetupFactory $quoteSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->quoteSetupFactory = $quoteSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        /* @var $quoteSetup \Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetup */
        $quoteSetup = $this->quoteSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        /* Price type custom column */
        $quoteSetup->addAttribute("quote_item", "new_price", ['type' => 'decimal']);
        /* Text type custom column */
        $quoteSetup->addAttribute("quote_item", "label", ['type' => 'text']);

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took this project file as an example:
https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-delivery-date/blob/master/SR/DeliveryDate/Setup/InstallSchema.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\DeliveryDate\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $installer->getTable('quote'),
            'delivery_date',
            [
                'type' => 'datetime',
                'nullable' => false,
                'comment' => 'Delivery Date',
            ]
        );

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```